# How can I fully log out of all Stack Exchange sites so I don't keep auto-logging in?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, login, logout

So [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188261/storing-stack-overflow-login-details-in-local-storage-considered-harmful) was swept under the rug, and that's well and fine and all.

But I can't log in to my other account because I keep getting pushed through auto login whenever I sign out and then try to log in with a different account. I logged out of Programmers and Meta, but I guess I'm still logged in somewhere else.

Will someone please direct me to a global-log-out, or a sign-in-with-different-user-name, or a list-all-your-current-logins-so-you-can-manually-log-out?

Comment: "sign-in-with-different-user-name" -- what do you need that for?

Comment: I am not the only Stack Exchange user who uses my desktop.

Comment: this should be solved by OS-level user accounts or at least browser-level profiles. There are other benefits to do it on a higher level than SO

Comment: @JanDvorak That shouldn't matter. How to log out of a site is a valid thing to want to do and to ask about - why are you grilling the asker about why on earth they'd want to do that? What if my friend sits down at my PC and wants to use their account? What if I have multiple accounts on here, which is completely a completely legitimate thing as long as I'm not cheating by having them vote for each other? It is ridiculous to demand a reason why on earth the asker should want to log out of a website, as if it's absurd they might ever want to. This is a good question.

Answer (score 4):

This *could* be something related to stale storage or cookies. Rather than have you try flushing a bunch of stuff, I manually flushed all sessions associated with your accounts on all sites. You should be logged out from *this* account everywhere.

If you're going to use two accounts (permitted, so long as they don't do favorable things for each other), I *really* recommend going incognito or into private browsing mode when you want to use the second one. Our global auth system is designed around the idea of *one* main account with many linked profiles, and we continue development in that direction, which means managing two accounts on the same browser could get even more inconvenient in the future.

Comment: I'm unable to log out just like @user. Should I post a new question so a mod can handle it? This solution doesn't seem scalable... :)

Comment: Better solution: two firefox profiles. Just choose a very extravagant desing style for the second one, so that you don't confuse youself.

Answer (score 2):

When I click on the [logout](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/logout) button I'm logged out on all StackExchange sites at once.

Comment: Well some of us aren't so fortunate.

Comment: Did you try to delete your cookies and local storrage? Maybe you run into a strage bug. Does it happen after a new clean login again?

Comment: I have a routine that I can do with Firebug, but I don't think that should be necessary. ..Once again surfacing my point that StackExchange's login system was engineered under the notion that no one shares computers.

Comment: I don't agree with you,  since if you click the logout button you are logged out on all StackExchange sites at once and also cross device.

Comment: The first link in the question has a screencast of what I'm dealing with. Nothing has changed. I hover over my name, click 'log out,' hit the button, and I am still automatically logged in to that same account when I try to log back in. No text field is shown.

Comment: Where is the logout button located? I can't find it, much to my own surprise, and hopefully I wouldn't have to navigate back to this answer just to log out in the future :)

Comment: You just need to hover above your nickname and reputation on the top, than a small info popup including the logout button appears.

Comment: @rekire Found it, thanks. It logs me out of this specific site. I remain logged in on other network sites, but I don't get user's experience of being logged right back in.

Comment: That is strange I can remember a case where I logged in on a friend's computer, after he logged me out I was also logged out on my notebook and my smartphone at once.